# How to control Firefox extension's sidebar using Webdriver

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am attempting to test a Firefox extension using the relevant driver provided by the `selenium-webdriver` NodeJs package.

The extension creates a [sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) whose handle I haven't been able to find using the [`getAllWindowHandles`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#getAllWindowHandles) method.  Having spent some time reading the documentation it also seems that Selenium doesn't support tabs; perhaps this is why.

Is there any way at all to retrieve a handle to a Firefox (extension) sidebar so as to be able to run tests on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is not possible to handle this in WebDriver. However, I have colleagues who are using a hybrid test automation framework between WebDriver for Web and for not supported parts- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). Sikuli is an image driven framework that you can use to automate the sidebar.

Another thing that I can suggest is to try to use the [Mozilla developer's API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/menubar).